# No sound on bluetooth device on Brave

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, brave

**Laptop**: HP 250 G8
**OS**: Ubuntu 22.04
**Bluetooth Device**: OnePlus Nord Buds

I am using Brave browser. There is no sound output in the bluetooth device. Instead the sound is coming through the system speaker.
The device selected in `Settings->Sound->Output Device` is my bluetooth device only.

`aplay -l`

```bash
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I also tried to play videos using VLC media player and they are working just fine. It is like just my **brave browser** is stuck on the laptop speaker.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure about the core problem, but if someone faces the same problem, here is a solution that worked for me.

1. Intsall `pavucontrol`

```bash
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

2. Channel your brave output to your bluetooth device.
3. Connect and Disconnect your device to make sure the problem doesn't persist.